# Oracle Hierarchical Query on Linked List Table

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have the following table that implements a linked list.  I want to query starting with rate_sequence_id of 1, and get the next record linked to it, which is 30 in this case.  So the query should return two rows (rate_sequence_id of 1, and 30).

However, the following query either returns only 1 row, or a "Loop" error, depending on which column comes first in the CONNECT BY clause.

Is what I am trying to do possible with this data?

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
CONNECT BY PRIOR RATE_SEQUENCE_ID = NEXT_RATE
START WITH RATE_SEQUENCE_ID = 1
```

Test Data:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
  RATE_SEQUENCE_ID      NUMBER(10,0),
  NEXT_RATE             NUMBER(10,0),
  DURATION              NUMBER,
  RATE                  NUMBER
);  


Insert into TEST (RATE_SEQUENCE_ID,NEXT_RATE,DURATION,RATE) values (50,51,28,0.99);
Insert into TEST (RATE_SEQUENCE_ID,NEXT_RATE,DURATION,RATE) values (51,51,112,9.99);
Insert into TEST (RATE_SEQUENCE_ID,NEXT_RATE,DURATION,RATE) values (1,30,28,0.99);
Insert into TEST (RATE_SEQUENCE_ID,NEXT_RATE,DURATION,RATE) values (30,30,112,14.99);
Insert into TEST (RATE_SEQUENCE_ID,NEXT_RATE,DURATION,RATE) values (0,0,0,0);
Insert into TEST (RATE_SEQUENCE_ID,NEXT_RATE,DURATION,RATE) values (31,0,30,0);
```

Comment: Which version of the database?  Hierarchical query is an area where Oracle have added lots of functionality in later releases.

Answer (score 1):

So this is your problem:

```
Insert into TEST (RATE_SEQUENCE_ID,NEXT_RATE,DURATION,RATE) values (30,30,112,14.99);
```

30 is connected to itself.  Is that right or is that a typo?

If that data is correct and you're using a modern version of Oracle you can use the NOCYCLE clause to escape from the loop. This is definitely in 10g (and maybe in 9i, my memory fails me here).  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm#i2053935).

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR RATE_SEQUENCE_ID = NEXT_RATE
START WITH RATE_SEQUENCE_ID = 1
```

Comment: Not a typo.  That means that the record is terminal.  But thanks, that is very helpful advice.  We're using 11G